# how to add unity game to visual studio C# app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game using Unity Engine 5.3.4
I have to add this game to my VS standalone app.
I mean when I run my VS C# app then I open a window of that app and click some button this game should be play
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can build your game with Unity and add to your VS project bin/debug folder this compiled game.

And inside of your button in VS project you need to write sth like:

```
Process.Start("//RelativeLocation/game.exe");
```